# Disable mysql 5.7 strict mode but log all issues

Tags: mysql

If its possible to disable strict mode but somehow get logged all problems that will happen if its being enabled?  I tried to set log-warnings to 2, but I still not getting strict mode errors, but see a lot of them when reenable it at mysql

Comment: If you disable strict sql mode, then the errors are downgraded to warnings. Therefore, in the log you should look for warnings, not errors.

Comment: but by default, they are going to error.log, right ? I see warnings there but not related any of those I saw when strict mode was enabled

Comment: There are several other types of warnings. You should test by deliberately issuing a statement that would cause an error is strict sql mode and then check how it looks like in the logs.